# Categorification of commutative sum

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, limits-colimits

In the introduction to locally presentable categories at [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+categories+-+introduction), it is stated:

> Now, the categorification of “commutative sum” is colimit.

My intuition in that context would be that the categorification of "commutative sum" is coproduct. It was clear for me that "adding elements" might be put in parallel with "taking a coproduct of objects". However, how should I interpret coequalisers or other kind of non-coproduct colimits?

Comment: A coproduct is a colimit.

Comment: But not all colimits are coproducts. Why are these "extra" colimits included in the categorification? Under this informal parallel, how should I understand coequalisers for example?

Comment: You can't; analogies break. Still, pushouts are amalgamated sums, ie. sums where some parts are glued together, so you might find that helpful, since pushouts + initial object suffice to construct other finite colimits.

Comment: @user54748 Do you know where I can find a concrete example where the analogy would break?

Comment: You're asking how to understand coequalisers when thinking about colimits as categorified sums. You can't really. Colimits are a generalization, and thus have something unique that's not present in the decategorified version. You can even argue that coequalisers are exactly that something, since every colimit can be computed in a canonical way as the coequaliser of two morphisms between coproducts.

Comment: You can think of colimits as generalizing sums in allowing you to glue objects together as you add them, and the way you glue is specified by a coequaliser, but you shouldn't take such metaphors too seriously or take them too far (although they can be useful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analogy just doesn't make that much sense yet, at this point. You need to see it taken farther first:

Taking the free abelian group on a set categorifies to freely completing a category under colimits; this is the [Yoneda embedding](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+embedding) $C \to [C^{op}, \text{Set}]$. Note that you can think of a presheaf $F : C^{op} \to \text{Set}$ as a "vector" whose "components" are the values of the presheaf, and it is possible to make sense of the statement that a presheaf is the "sum" of its components in the colimit sense, by writing a presheaf as a colimit of representable presheaves.

Next, given two finite sets $X, Y$ we can consider linear maps $\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}[Y]$ from the free abelian group on $X$ to the free abelian group on $Y$. It's not hard to see that these correspond to $|X| \times |Y|$ (or is it the other way around?) matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$.

This categorifies as follows. The category of cocontinuous functors $[C^{op}, \text{Set}] \to [D^{op}, \text{Set}]$ is, by the universal property of the Yoneda embedding, equivalent to the category of functors $C \times D^{op} \to \text{Set}$. These are called [profunctors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor) or bimodules, and they are intuitively "matrices of sets." Composition is given by an operation which generalizes tensor product of bimodules and which you can think of as categorifying matrix multiplication, but where the sum is a colimit, or more precisely a [coend](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end).

For more along these lines see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2016/05/31/higher-linear-algebra/), which replaces $\text{Set}$ with $\text{Mod}(k)$ for $k$ a commutative ring but is otherwise about the same thing.

Also keep in mind that categorifications are not unique. You could choose to use only coproducts as your categorification but you can do a lot more if you use colimits instead.